# How do I remove the last comma from in foreach loop

Tags: json, foreach

Note: I'm not a developer but I'm intrigued on how to fix this issue that we are having.

See the code below:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">

    {
    "@@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@@type": "Product",
    "name": "@Model.ProductDetails.ProductTitle",
    "image": [ @foreach (var link in Model.ProductDetails.ProductImageList)
    {
        @Html.Raw("\"" + Url.Absolute(link) + "\", ");
    }  ],
    "description": "@Model.ProductDetails.ProductDescription",
    "brand": "Sample"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You could get the ammount of Images in ImageList and then check while looping, if your current Image is the last one. If it is the last one print the link without the comma.

Comment: @Strohhut I'm sorry as I don't understand how to do that. Usually, we have 3-4 images for each of the pages where this code is applied.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't put foreach outside of the schema object, calculate the images[] first, then put images[] into the schema object like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = [];
    foreach (var link in Model.ProductDetails.ProductImageList){
        images.push(Html.Raw(Url.Absolute(link)));
    }
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@@type": "Product",
    "name": "@Model.ProductDetails.ProductTitle",
    "image": images,
    "description": "@Model.ProductDetails.ProductDescription",
    "brand": "Sample"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If say I have 2-3 images on each of these pages, how should that reflect on the code? Thanks for your time I really appreciate it!